# How does AsReference on the ProtoMemberAttribute work

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have a distributed client - server application (multiple servers). The user can send data from one server to another. This is only allowed of the (customer defined) structure (aka `DataType`) is identical on all servers.

Therefore I do serialize the `DataType` with *protobuf-net* and compare the MD5 hash of the binary data.

But here is the catch: the binary data is different (and therefore the MD5 hash) but all attributes (decorated with `ProtoMemberAttribute`) have the exact same value!

I have several fields which have `[ProtoMember(5, AsReference = true)]` defined - which I suspect that the generation of the internal identification tag is not deterministic.

Does anyone know how that generation works in detail?

Is it in general a bad idea to rely on binary protobuf equality?

We are using VS2010. Net 4.0. an protobuf-net 2.0.0.668.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm *not aware* of a reason it would be non-deterministic, but I also wouldn't absolutely guarantee it in every case.

> Is it in general a bad idea to rely on binary protobuf equality?

Yes, it is. The format itself has multiple things where the same data can be presented differently:

- fields can be in any order; libraries *should* present them in an ascending order, but are not *required* to
- merged (concatenated) data can, as an example of the above, mean that semantically identical data can have multiple forms, since (as long as the fields don't collide) "chunk A, chunk B" should be semantically the same as "chunk B, chunk A"
- the format does not explicitly disallow subnormal forms for varint encoding; by which I mean that the *normal and expected* representation of `5` is `0x05`, but `0x8500`, `0x858000`, `0x85808000` (etc) are *also* all perfectly legal varint representations of `5`
- if you're using dynamic typing (protobuf-net only, not a core protobuf feature), then the type's assembly version will be part of the output; this can change

Comment: How is the reference tag generated exactly? I was not able to find this in the source code. I do serialize an Array of 'DataType's which contain child 'DataType's. Some of the children of some 'DataType's are different on some servers (have more children). It seems to me (when looking at the binary data) that the reference tag has an offset of 1 or 2 - as if there has been a value inserted. No dynamic typing, all well defined. I have also done the sorting of attributes.